# Missing step to my conversion of units

Tags: homogeneous-equation

The problem I am trying to solve is converting 100m^3 to ft^3
100(m^3) (3.28ft/1m)^3 = 3529ft^3
What my brain is having trouble comprehending is (3.28ft/1m)^3... if I were to multiply only the units in the bracket it would be 3.28ft^3/1m^3 which does not lead me to the 3529ft^3 answer. alternatively if I multiply everything inside the bracket it gives me 9.84ft^3/3m^3 which also doesn't get me to the desired answer. I'm assuming I need to get m^3 as a denominator so I can cancel it out as a numerator on the first segment.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$$(100 m^3) \cdot \left( \frac{3.28 ft}{1m}\right)^3 = (100 m^3) \cdot \left( \frac{3.28^3 ft^3}{1m^3}\right) \approx 3529 ft^3$$

The $m^3$ does get cancelled out.

Comment: Thank you Siong for your help, I see where I was mistaken.